# Clone an image in cv2 Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. What is the Python function which act the same as *cv::clone()* in C++?

I just try to get a rect by

```
    rectImg = img[10:20, 10:20]
```

but when I draw a line on it, I find the line appear both on *img* and the rectImage, so, how can I get this done?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[Abid Rahman K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533078/clone-an-image-in-cv2-python/16535453#16535453) is correct, but you say that you are using cv2 which inherently uses NumPy arrays. So, to make a complete different copy of say "myImage":

```
newImage = myImage.copy()
```

The above is enough. There isn't any need to import NumPy (`numpy`).

Answer (score 69):

If you use `cv2`, the correct method is to use the `.copy()` method in NumPy. It will create a copy of the array you need. Otherwise it will produce only a view of that object.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(10*10).reshape((10, 10))

In [4]: y = x[3:7, 3:7].copy()

In [6]: y[2, 2] = 1000

In [8]: 1000 in x
Out[8]: False     # See, 1000 in y doesn't change values in x, the parent array.
```

Comment: They are just numbers in range 0-100. Just print `x` and `y` after each step. Then you will get the idea.

Answer (score 16):

Using Python 3 and opencv-python version 4.4.0, the following code should work:

```
img_src = cv2.imread('image.png')
img_clone = img_src.copy()
```

Comment: is that actually an answer or a question? "I try using..."

Comment: an answer actually @Ruli

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Python standard library. Make a shallow copy of the original image as follows:

```
import copy

original_img = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")
clone_img = copy.copy(original_img)
```

Comment: Shallow copies are harmful (RAM ownership is unclear, access-performance is unclear etc).

Answer (score 1):

My favorite method uses cv2.copyMakeBorder with no border, like so.

```
copy = cv2.copyMakeBorder(original,0,0,0,0,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the `copyMakeBorder` variant over the regular 'copy` ? Is it an attempt to avoid the notion of nparrays (which Python-OpenCV matrices are) appearing in source code?